# Customize appearance of UINavigationBar

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface, uikit

I'm new to iOS UI design, and I'm working on writing code that displays highly customized navigation bar, which will be used my transportation app.

Here are features of my navigation bar (see figure below):
[image: Custom UINavigationBar Blueprint]

1. `Layout Margins` are `18`, and `Space` between its subviews is `9`.
2. All of its subviews' `height` is `44`, and all `UIBarButtonItem` is rectangle.
3. `backBarButtonItem` should be positioned same as `leftBarButtonItem`.
4. In **normal state**, its `height` is `80`.
5. In **expanded state** (*such as direction fields view in map apps*), its `titleView` will contain two `UITextField`s, so its `height` should be `136`.

See Real Design Screenshots
[image: See Real Design Screenshots]
So I've declared subclass of `UINavigationBar`, and connected custom class to `Navigation Bar` object in storyboard using Identity Inspector. However, I'm not sure where to begin. Though I overrode `sizeThatFits(_ size:)` function to make its `height` long for now, the subviews are close to bottom. I could't find a best practice to customize `UINavigationBar` like Google Maps, Uber, etc.

How can I implement such navigation bar by subclassing `UINavigationBar`? Or are there any other solutions?

Comment: Subclassing `UINavigationBar` is not recommended. You should explore `UIAppearance` class to get the desired UI.

Comment: I like your design screenshot above, how did you make it?

Comment: Why don't you just use a simple view and add the desired subviews to it? In my opinion it's more easy and effective way of doing what you want.

Comment: @Adeel Thanks! However, the subview remains in place  when I push/pop another navigation item.

Comment: Can you share a screenshot or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can subclass UINavigationBar with the following steps..

1. Add a new class(subclass of UINavigationBar), select your ViewController's NavigationController. Select ViewController Navigation Bar from the Document Outline. Set the class to your custom class.
2. In your custom class, do as following..

   ```
   override func sizeThatFits(_ size: CGSize) -> CGSize {
       var bound = super.sizeThatFits(size)
       bound.height += sizeToAdd //The height you want
       return bound
   }

   override init(frame: CGRect) {
       super.init(frame: frame)
       self.setup()
   }

   required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
       super.init(coder: aDecoder)
       self.setup()
   }

   override func layoutSubviews() {  
       super.layoutSubviews()

   //If you don't override this function and do as follows, you'll 
   //find that all NavigationButtons and the Title positioned at the 
   //bottom of your navigation bar.(for the Title, we still need to 
   //add one line in setup())

       let classes = ["UIButton", "UINavigationItemView",             
       "UINavigationButton"]

       for object in self.subviews{

           let classOfObject = String(describing: type(of: object))

           if classes.contains(classOfObject){
               var objectFrame = object.frame
               objectFrame.origin.y -= self.sizeToAdd
               object.frame = objectFrame
           }
       }

   }
   ```
3. Now in setup(), add the following code to get the Title uplifted as one would want(typically!)

   ```
   func setup() -> Void {
       self.setTitleVerticalPositionAdjustment(-self.sizeToAdd, for: 
       .default)
   }
   ```
4. Now, you can design a view as you want (Here, I've loaded a custom view with XIB, you can do with code too.) and add as a subview to your navigation bar, in your ViewController. For example, in your viewDidLoad..

   ```
   YOURVIEW.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 44, width: 
   (self.navigationController?.navigationBar.bounds.width)!, height: 
   (self.navigationController?.navigationBar.bounds.height)! + 
   self.sizeToAdd)//The height
   self.navigationController?.navigationBar.
   addSubview(YOURVIEW)
   ```
5. So, you can subclass your navigation bar this way. But when you'll push any other viewController onto this one, you'll see (if you haven't embedded  another NavigationController to the viewController that you're pushing) that the view remains as it was in pushed viewController too. You can remove it from super view before pushing any other viewController. Just removing it will not give a good user experience as the other system elements(if there are any) will fade out nicely. So, do the following to give a good user experience...

   ```
   override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
       super.viewWillAppear(true)

       if(!(self.navigationController?.navigationBar.subviews.contains
       (YOURVIEW))!){ //Either get it working with setting a tag to 
                      //your view and checking it against all subviews 
                      //if you haven't use XIB
           self.navigationController?.navigationBar.
           addSubview(YOURVIEW)
       }else {
           UIView.transition(with: YOURVIEW, 
           duration: 0.5, options: [ANYOPTIONS], animations: {
               self.profileNavigationView.alpha = 1.0
       }) { (success) in

       }
   }
   ```

   }

   ```
   override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
       super.viewWillDisappear(true)

       UIView.transition(with: YOURVIEW, duration: 
       0.5, 
       options: [ANYOPTIONS], animations: {
           self.profileNavigationView.alpha = 0.0
       }) { (success) in
           //remove it here if you want
       }
   ```

   }